# MySQL query join this same table twice without duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, join, mysqli

I have a table `users`

```
id, ip, opponent
1, 123.123.123, 2
2, 123.123.123, 1
3, 123.123.123, NULL
```

I need query that, show me list of versus ips without duplicates.

```
ip_first_opponent, ip_second_opponent
```

How can I do it, i am newbie in sql.

Comment: your table(s) defintion, your data and expected result would be helpful. Your question is not easy to understand...

Comment: from example from my post. i need ips who have opponent = id.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to get all the ips of the opponents of the user with id x, you can do the following:

SELECT DISTINCT(opponents.id) FROM users AS me, users AS opponents WHERE me.id=x and me.opponentId=opponents.id

(So you join the table users to itself with the constraint that the opponent id is the same as the id of the opponent and the DISTINCT only outputs different ips.)

Edit:
Since you want to select the ip of the user and his opponents, the query becomes:

SELECT DISTINCT me.ip, opponents.ip FROM users AS me, users AS opponents WHERE me.opponentId=opponents.id

Comment: me.id==x hmm, i dont understand

Comment: Sorry, you should use just 'me.id=x', without the double '='.

Comment: why you put `and` to the end of query, and what is x?

Comment: not complete awake anymore :)
The and should be between the two where clauses, and x is the id of the user whose opponents you want to know

Comment: i want to display all `fights` with ips from opponents

Comment: what are the columns you want to see in the output?
like (id, opponent_id, opponent_ip)?

Comment: i want to see ip, opponent_ip

Comment: all without duplicates.

Comment: SELECT a.ip, b.ip FROM `users` as a inner join users as b on a.opponent = b.id  like this, but without duplicates

Comment: Just use SELECT DISTINCT instead of SELECT and it should work fine

Comment: could you post the exact column names of the table and the query you are using?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/CB9bljy.jpg, SELECT DISTINCT a.ip, b.ip, a.id FROM `users` as a inner join users as b on a.opponent = b.hash

Comment: Suppose the data is:
ID, HASH, IP, OPPONENT:
1, player1, 1.1.1.1, player2|
2, player1, 1.1.1.1, player2

what output would you want?

Maybe it is better to store users and fights in different tables, with figths like: player1, player2

Comment: @JanuszJanusz The problem with the id is that it has an index so (id,a.ip,b.ip) wil be different for all fights. When you group them by a.ip an b.ip, what id would you expect to be shown?

Comment: id_1 opponent, id_2 opponent, sorry my fault.